# How can I parse a VCARD in a XML file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to parse an XML file in which there is some VCARD. I need the info: FN, NOTE (SIREN and A) and print them as a list as FN, SIREN_A. I would also like to add them in a list if the string in the description equals "diviseur" only

I've tried different things (vobject, finditer) but none of them work. For my parser, I'm using the library xml.etree.ElementTree and pandas which usually are causing some incompatibilies.

code python :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import vobject
newlist=[]
data=[]
data.append(newlist)
diviseur=[]
tree=ET.parse('test_oc.xml')
root=tree.getroot()
newlist=[]
for lifeCycle in root.findall('{http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM}lifeCycle'):
    for contribute in lifeCycle.findall('{http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM}contribute'):
        for entity in  contribute.findall('{http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM}entity'):
            vcard = vobject.readOne(entity)
            siren = vcard.contents['note'].value,":",vcard.contents['fn'].value
            print ('siren',siren.text)
    for date in contribute.findall('{http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM}date'):
        for description in date.findall('{http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM}description'):                       
            entite=description.find('{http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM}string')
            print ('Type entité:', entite.text)
            newlist.append(entite)
            j=0
            for j in range(len(entite)-1):
                if entite[j]=="diviseur":
                    diviseur.append(siren[j])
                    print('diviseur:', diviseur)
                    newlist.append(diviseur)
data.append(newlist)                    
print(data)
```

xml file to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<lom:lom xmlns:lom="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM" xmlns:lomfr="http://www.lom-fr.fr/xsd/LOMFR"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM">
    <lom:version uniqueElementName="version">
        <lom:string language="http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/iso639-2/fre">V4.1</lom:string>
    </lom:version>
    <lom:lifeCycle uniqueElementName="lifeCycle">
        <lom:contribute>
            <lom:entity><![CDATA[ 
            BEGIN:VCARD
            VERSION:4.0
            FN:Cailler
            N:;Valérie;;Mr;
            ORG:Veoli
            NOTE:SIREN=203025106
            NOTE :ISNI=0000000000000000
            END:VCARD
            ]]></lom:entity>
            <lom:date uniqueElementName="date">
                <lom:dateTime uniqueElementName="dateTime">2019-07-10</lom:dateTime>
                <lom:description uniqueElementName="description">
                    <lom:string>departure</lom:string>
                </lom:description>
            </lom:date>
        </lom:contribute>
        <lom:contribute>
            <lom:entity><![CDATA[ 
            BEGIN:VCARD
            VERSION:4.0
            FN:Besnard
            N:;Ugo;;Mr;
            ORG:MG
            NOTE:SIREN=501 025 205
            NOTE :A=0000 0000
            END:VCARD
            ]]></lom:entity>
            <lom:date uniqueElementName="date">
                <lom:dateTime uniqueElementName="dateTime">2019-07-10</lom:dateTime>
                <lom:description uniqueElementName="description">
                    <lom:string>diviseur</lom:string>
                </lom:description>
            </lom:date>
        </lom:contribute>
    </lom:lifeCycle>
</lom:lom>
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser_export_csv_V2.py", line 73, in 
    vcard = vobject.readOne(entity)
  File "C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vobject\base.py", line 1156, in readOne
    allowQP))
  File "C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vobject\base.py", line 1089, in readComponents
    for line, n in getLogicalLines(stream, allowQP):
  File "C:\Users\b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vobject\base.py", line 869, in getLogicalLines
    val = fp.read(-1)
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: That's not a valid XML file, can you remove the syntax errors? (Also fix the Python indentation and state the exact errors you get)

Comment: Look at vobject library https://pypi.org/project/vobject/

Comment: @Tomalak is it better right now?

Comment: @mzjn it should be ok right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

- `entity` is an `Element` instance, and vCard is a plain text data format. `vobject.readOne()` expects text.
- There is unwanted whitespace adjacent to the vCard properties in the XML file.
- `NOTE :ISNI=0000000000000000` is invalid; it should be `NOTE:ISNI=0000000000000000` (space removed).
- `vcard.contents['note']` is a list and does not have a `value` property.

Here is code that probably doesn't produce exactly what you want, but I hope it helps:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import vobject

NS = {"lom": "http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/LOM"}

tree = ET.parse('test_oc.xml')

for contribute in tree.findall('.//lom:contribute', NS):
    desc_string = contribute.find('.//lom:string', NS)
    print(desc_string.text)

    entity = contribute.find('lom:entity', NS)
    txt = entity.text.replace(" ", "")  # Text with spaces removed
    vcard = vobject.readOne(txt)

    for p in vcard.contents["note"]:
        print(p.name, p.value)
    for p in vcard.contents["fn"]:
        print(p.name, p.value)

    print()
```

Output:

```
departure
NOTE SIREN=203025106
NOTE ISNI=0000000000000000
FN Cailler

diviseur
NOTE SIREN=501025205
NOTE A=00000000
FN Besnard
```